# how to make a JavaScript transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a JavaScript transition that is similar to the one on this website:
http://osc4.template-help.com/wt_32608/index.html#.

Could you please give me some suggestions and show me some libraries that would make it easier 
to implement?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you meant "library" rather than "literary".

It looks like this site is using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) along with some custom code, although such an effect could be achieved in pure CSS3 (at the cost of some cross browser compatibility).

Comment: fixed , are there more details about jQuery libraries , I'm new in jQuery .

Comment: There are many, many articles on the internet about jQuery, just have a search around. Also, you might want to look into jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com) if you are going into user interface creation.

Comment: one more question , When I search in more specific what I should look for in jQuery libraries . is there any tags can help .

Comment: If I want a jQuery UI like the example above .is  jquery Slider the right tag ??